# Is it possible to access AnalyticSnapshots programmatically in order to discern AnalyticSnapshotMapping[] data?

Tags: metadata-api, analytics, reports-api, analytics-api

Salesforce Metadata API lists AnalyticSnapshots as a metadata type here:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_analyticsnapshot.htm and mappings as a field here: 
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_analyticsnapshot.htm#AnalyticSnapshotMapping.

How could one access these fields programmatically to use in other salesforce code? As a developer, I would like to be able to access analytic snapshot mappings in order to determine what the fields are mapped to and to be able to use that information in code. For example, if the Account ID was mapped to an Account ID/Number field on the analytic snapshot/report, I would like to be able to discern the exact field the account ID was mapped to. Is that possible with analytic snapshots and what might be the best way to code a solution for that?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Salesforce1 Reporting REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/)?

Comment: I did take a look at the reporting api through the workbench. I was not able to locate any snapshot or mapping fields for the snapshots there. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: If you didn't find it there, I wouldn't know where to look.